# how to locate the equations to the left in "itemize" environment as shown in the picture

Tags: equations, itemize

[image: align the equations to the left]

I want to put the equations in the itemize environment, however, the equations are centered. Do you guys know how to generated the layout shown in the picture?

Comment: As (almost) always, it's helpful (sometimes absolutely necessary) to provide [an MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that). Right off the bat, if you're using an `equation` environment, or even just the display math mode `\[ ... \]` it's standard behaviour for equations to be centred everywhere (yes this is changeable). But the more you give us, the more we can give you

Comment: @Joe did you try it? `\documentclass{article}\begin{document}\begin{itemize}\item{Partition of unity.\[ x + y \]}\end{itemize}\end{document}`

Comment: Thank Jeffery. I tried this, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to do this, including the `enum`-package, which could be great for consistency, or a simple `newcommand`.

**Output**

[image]

**Code**

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\alignleft}{%
    \@fleqntrue\@mathmargin3em%
    \setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{4pt} %
    \setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{4pt} %
    }
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\alignleft
    \item Partition of unity
            \begin{equation*}
                \sum^{p+1}_{i=1} B^p_i \ldots
            \end{equation*}
    \item Pointwise nonnegativity
            \begin{equation*}
                B^p_i       B^p_i       B^p_i       B^p_i \ldots
            \end{equation*}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This looks pretty good. Thank you. The only problem is that the line spacing between the texts and the equations is a little bit big. Do you know how to set up the line spacing here?

Comment: I think it is something like this: `\setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{0pt} \setlength{\belowdisplayshortskip}{0pt} \setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{0pt} \setlength{\abovedisplayshortskip}{0pt}` I'm currently not at my computer

Comment: Thanks. This seems have an effect on the whole document.  What  I want is just change the spacing for these itemize environment.

Comment: If you put the code within the same group, it will stay locally. Put it right before `\leftalign`.

Comment: Do you mean using the code like this:\begin{itemize}
\setlength{\belowdisplayshortskip}{0pt}
\alignleft
\item  Partition of unity.
\begin{align*}
\sum_{i = 1}^{p+1}{B_{i,p}}(\xi) = 1  
\end{align*}
\setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{0pt} 
\end{itemize}

Comment: @Joe I made an edit with it.

Comment: This new version works so well. Thank you so much, Runartrollet.

Comment: @Joe I found a better way to do this. See my other answer. I think I'll delete this one.

Answer (score 2):

Set the items as inline math prepended with `\qquad` (a 2em space). You can switch to `\displaystyle` if needed:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
  \item {\itshape Partition of unity.}

  \qquad $\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^{p+1} B^p_i (\xi) \quad \forall \xi \in [-1,1]$

  \item {\itshape Pointwise nonnegativity.}

  \qquad $B_i^p(\xi) \geq 0 \quad \forall \xi \in [-1,1]$

  \item {\itshape Endpoint interpolation.}

  \qquad $B_1^p(-1) = B_{p+1}^p(1) = 1$

  \item {\itshape Symmetry.}

  \qquad $B_i^p(\xi) = B_{p+1-i}^p(\xi) \quad \forall \xi \in [-1,1]$.
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to do it, which is probably better than my other answer. You get the correct spacing, and you can align the equations better to each other, if desir​eble, as the equations are kept in just one environment. Also, less code.

**Output**

[image]

**Code**

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\alignleft}{%
    \@fleqntrue\@mathmargin3em%
    \setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{4pt} %
    \setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{4pt} %
    }
\makeatother
\begin{document}
{%
\alignleft
\begin{gather*}
\intertext{\textbullet\  Partition of unity}
    \sum^{p+1}_{i=1} B^p_i \ldots
\intertext{\textbullet\  Pointwise nonnegativity}
    B^p_i \ldots
\end{gather*}
}%
\end{document}
```